# Android - cordova - A network error has occurred

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

**My Environment**
Android Studio 1.0.1
cordova-4.1.0

I'm trying to access my website at **`http://example.com/index.php`** from the line   `super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());`

As the application runs on My physical device (Moto g2, Android 5) splash screen to `MainActivity extends CordovaActivity` works fine but on `MainActivity` it shows a alert with a title: **Application Error and body**: There was a network error. `(http://example.com/index.php)`

I have set the needed permission for Internet Access `AndroidManifest.xml`

Recently i have updated cordova from 2.9 to 4.1.; Log cat doesn't show's any record related to my application while running application. Also i tried to replace `"http://example.com/index.php"` with the **"file:///android_asset/www/example.html"** which worked fine, so i made a change in it and redirected to `"http://example.com/index.php"` form `onLoad` or by giving link it from example.html page but it fails to redirect.

anybody has a solution or a trick to solve it?

Comment: make sure whether your URL is `http://` or `https://`. and try access the same url in mobile browser with same internet connection

Comment: Its working fine on browser and its a http not https (confirmed!)

Comment: You can not set external web url in phonegap. but if you need to open url from your app you can use InAppBrowser plugin.

Comment: @Manish Parakhiya - InAppBrowser plugin are already added!

Answer (score 1):

Add `www` before example. like this `http://www.example.com/index.php` it should work.

If still it is not working try debugging using chrome. This link might help you
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

Comment: You can use same tool for console log.